# Can't post data to web server using GPRS GSM A6 and Arduino

Tags: php, networking, arduino, gsm, gprs

I've been trying to post data to server for sometime now. Even though I am getting OK response, data is not posted to the server.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myGsm(7,8);

void setup() {
  myGsm.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(1000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPMUX=0\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(2000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CGATT=1\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(1000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CSTT=\"internet\",\"\",\"\"\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(5000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIICR\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(5000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIFSR\r"); //RESPONSE= Returns an IP
  delay(2000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"159.203.180.107\", 80\r") //RESPONSE= CONNECTED OK
  delay(3000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSEND\r"); //RESPONSE= >
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("POST http://159.203.180.107/Code/ HTTP/1.1");
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("Host: 159.203.180.107");
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("Content-Type: application/json");
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("Content-Length: 25\r\n");
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("{\"Celsius\":\"TEMPERATURE\"}");
  delay(500);
  myGsm.write(0x1A); // Ctrl Z
  delay(10000);
  /*
    After sending all these instructions, I get the following response,
    OK
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Friday December, 22
    +TCPCLOSE=0
    OK
  */
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPCLOSE"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(1000);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT"); //RESPONSE= OK
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
}
```

So, as you can see, I get a `200 OK` response after sending the data, but the data is not written into the file in the server. The existing content in the file is erased, but new data is not written in that file.

Here's my PHP file in the server:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    file_put_contents("data.txt", $_REQUEST);
    die("<br>DONE!");
?>
```

So, what could be the problem here? Is there something wrong with the PHP file in the server? Please help. I've also posted this same question in one of the Arduino communities but it didn't help.

Comment: PHP doesn't automatically parse JSON.

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't automatically parse JSON.

You need to either post it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which looks like

```
Celsius=TEMPERATURE
```

or parse the POST payload yourself

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code work easily because i change part of your code and added some command in a function also i tested finally code and it worked for me.also do not forget change  server code like  answer inserted in this post.
thanks from all.

My Server Code:

```
 $res=[];
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$res['name']=$data['Celsius'];
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myGsm(10,11);
void updateSerial()
{
  delay(2000);
  while (Serial.available()) {
    myGsm.write(Serial.read());//Data received by Serial will be outputted by mySerial
  }
  while (myGsm.available()) {
    Serial.write(myGsm.read());//Data received by myGsm will be outputted by Serial
}
  }
}
void setup() {
  myGsm.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPMUX=0\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CGATT=1\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
 updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CSTT=\"internet\",\"\",\"\"\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIICR\r"); //RESPONSE= OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIFSR\r"); //RESPONSE= Returns an IP
 updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"example.com\", 80\r"); //RESPONSE= CONNECTED OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSEND\r"); //RESPONSE= >
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("POST example.com/index.php/ HTTP/1.1");
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("Host: example.com");
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("Content-Type: application/json");
 updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("Content-Length: 25\r\n");
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("{\"Celsius\":\"TEMPERATURE\"}");
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.write(0x1A); // Ctrl Z
  delay(3000);
  updateSerial();
  /*
    After sending all these instructions, I get the following response,
    OK
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Friday December, 22
    +TCPCLOSE=0
    OK
  */
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPCLOSE"); //RESPONSE= OK
  updateSerial();
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT"); //RESPONSE= OK
 updateSerial();
}
void loop() {
}
```